# Get text not contained within a tag

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I want to extract text which has no tag.

The HTML looks something like like this:

```
<a href="asdsd.com">hello</a>

I want this text

<strong>not this</strong>
```

How do I get that text?

I am thinking I can read it into a string and then search for the parts in the `<a>` and `<strong>` tags but don't know how to write it.

p.s. I have checked thoroughly and there is no `<div>`, `<b>`, `<p>` or any other tags. It hangs just like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the text nodes that contain a sibling.  If they have a previous or next one, then you know it's a node you want.

```
Dim query = doc.DocumentNode                           _
    .DescendantNodes                                   _
    .OfType(Of HtmlTextNode)                           _
    .Where(Function(t) t.PreviousSibling IsNot Nothing _
                OrElse t.NextSibling IsNot Nothing)
```